# How to check if a xml file contains specific element using linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, exception, linq-to-xml

In my XML file i want to check if i have and device element in my xml file

i try this code but give me  `Null Reference Exception` if it not found a device element

```
public bool HaveAnyDevice()
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
    return !doc.Element("Settings").Elements("Device").Any();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting a NRE then your `doc.Element("Settings")` is null. You may check it before checking the next element.

```
return doc.Element("Settings") != null && 
       doc.Element("Settings").Elements("Device").Any();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. I think you don't have element `Settings` in your xml. So, just verify if it exists before trying to get it's elements:

```
 public bool HaveAnyDevice()
 {
     XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
     var settings = doc.Element("Settings");
     return (settings != null) && settings.Elements("Device").Any();
 }
```